# Angular component calling function directly from html breaks unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

I am assigned to fix unit tests on a component where another component's public function is called directly from the HTML file, and the unit test doesn't seem to understand this.

My HTML file looks like this:

```
<some-component *ngIf="otherComponent" (click)="otherComponent.doSomething()"></some-component>
<other-component #otherComponent></other-component>
```

The code works. However, the unit test fails with the following error:

```
TypeError: _r4.doSomething is not a function
```

Is there any quick fix for the unit test to run? I know the entire function calling process shouldn't be done this way, but I am required to fix the unit test without making (major) changes to the implementation.

Comment: I think you have to mock "otherComponent" variable. Could you show declaration of unit test for that component?

Comment: The unit test is the default unit test generated by Angular, no changes were made to it. I've tried doing `component['otherComponent'] = TestBed.createComponent(OtherComponent);` inside the unit test's beforeEach() function, but it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I think first you have to create child component: `child = TestBed.createComponent(OtherComponent)`, then you have to assign mocked method to that component, like that `child.doSomething = () => null`, and finally assign it to current component `component.otherComponent = child`.